# does jquery fadein() has any preconditions / constraints in terms of css or html elem it supports

Tags: jquery, css

I am using

```
$("#somedivid").click( function() {
    $("#somedivid").fadeIn('slow');
}); 

// CSS Class
.niceclass {
    width:10px;
    height:40px;
    background: #EDE9E3;
    border:1px solid grey;
    margin-left:2px;
    float:left;
    display:none;
}
```

Its not working, I have added display:none; as per a documentation comment. Are there any preconditions that the div i am fadingIn. If Yes pls list all.

Comment: If the element is `display: none` how can you click it to make it fade in?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan do you mean to say we need to have two elems, and the fadein elem should be hidden ??

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible to click on the hidden element!

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $("#anotherElement").fadeIn('slow');
});  


#anotherElement {
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Well if you want the element to be hidden from the start then set `display:none;`. Here's a simple test.

http://jsfiddle.net/HPknG/